# Spring MVC Scoped Bean Dependencies and Race Conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I have some serious doubts regarding scope bean dependencies because of lack of spring knowledge.

I have read reference manual at 3.5.4.5 Scoped beans as dependencies and have implemented sucessfully an example about it.

However before going further more, I wanted to share my concerns.

Let me to share my use case and little implementation details

**For each user request I would like to create a city for per user.**

```
@Configuration
public class CityFactory{

   @Bean(name = {"currentCity" , "loggedInCity"})
   @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
   @Autowired
   public CityBean getCityBean(HttpServletRequest request) {
      return CityUtil.findCityWithHostName(request.getServerName());
   }
```

**For each request I want to inject this city into a singleton scoped controller which is default scope for controller.**

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    CityBean city;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(@PathVariable("name") String name, Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.addAttribute("hello", name);
        model.addAttribute("test", "test in " + city.getDomainName() + "  !!!    ");

        return new ModelAndView("v3/test", "m", model);
    }
}
```

My questions:

1) Is there any race condition? I am afraid of context switches which will destroy my application in a multi request environment.

2) I am aware of another solution which creating a controller per request but it is more error prone than current solution. Because another developer can forget scoping controllers to make request.

How can I make controllers globally request scope? Just because of being little curious.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No race conditions - each request has its own thread

But I think there's an easier way to do what you want. You can have your `CityBean`:

```
@Service
public class CityBean {
    public String getDomainName(String serverName) {
        // obtain the name based on the server name
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

- `@Autowired CityBean bean`
- pass `HttpServletRequest` as argument to the method, and call `cityBean.getDomainName(request.getServerName());`

(If you use some ORM, perhaps you'll have a `City` entity, which you can fetch and pass around, just beware of lazy collections)

Comment: CityBean class is coming from another legacy library. Thank you very much for your suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

There are no race conditions here.

That's the point of scoped proxies - the instance of `CityBean` injected into `DemoController` is a proxy which delegates calls of its method to the actual request-bound instance of `CityBean`, so that each request works with its own `CityBean`.

I agree that you shouldn't make the controller itself request-scoped - it would be confusing for other people since it's not a typical approach in Spring MVC applications.

You can also follow the approach suggest by Bozho and get rid of request-scoped bean at all, though that approach has a drawback since it requires you to add extra argument to your controller methods.